# How can I append button dynamically to a textbox for only the first value in an array?

Tags: jquery

```
var xml="<button>+</button>"
    var details = [{
        "Name": "Bhanu",
        "Phone": [ "546546", "564654" ]
    }
    {
        "Name": "Shiva",
        "Phone": [ "65654", "654665" ]
    }];

    var dis = "<button id='closing3'>Close</button>" + '<br>' + "Name: <input type='text' id='textbox' value='" + data1[i].Name + "'>" + '<br>' + "PhoneNo: ";

    for (j = 0; j < data1[i].PhoneNo.length; j++) {
        dis = dis + "<input type='text' class='append' id='textbox" + data1[i].PhoneNo[j] + "' value='" + data1[i].PhoneNo[j] + "'><br>";

        if (i == 0) {
            $("#textbox" + data1[i].PhoneNo[j]).html(xml);
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Here what I am doing is when there is an array in PhoneNo and when we display those numbers in text boxes dynamically ,then how can we append a button beside first text box which contains first number.

The output must be

```
 PhoneNo:123456 in textbox + button
 PhoneNo:65465465 in textbox
```

Comment: You can't append any HTML to an input. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Also, your `details` array has invalid syntax - you need a comma (`,`) between the objects. Finally, your jQuery selector finds nothing because the HTML string in `dis` hasn't been added to the DOM yet.

Comment: Append `textbox` to a `textbox`? You can't.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: change the code I wrote yesterday to add a button

Comment: No..That was just appending a button to a static textbox.But now We have an array in PhoneNo ..Only for 1st number "+" button should be appended and for next textboxes "-" button should be appended.I was trying for this by adding a condition above "if "

Answer (score 0):

I added a div with id=phone around your phone number

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9gccfw73/)

```
$.each(item.PhoneNo, function (i, num) {
    if(item.PhoneNo.length > 0 && i==0) $("<input type='button' id='button10' name='number' value='+'>").appendTo("#phone");
    if(i>0) {
        $("<input type='text' class='append' id='textbox1"+i+"' name='number'>").appendTo("#phone");
        $("<input type='button' id='button1"+i+"' name='number' value='-'>").appendTo("#phone");
    }
    $("#textbox1" + i).val(num);
});
```